# Use react-virtualized Window Scroller with frozen header and footer

Tags: flexbox, react-virtualized

I am using react-virtualized WindowScroller with CellMeasurer to scroll through a 100 sample records and by itself, it works great.

[image: react-virtualized window scroller]

Now, when I place this component in a content pane with a frozen header and footer (using flex) above and below it, react-virtualized does not bring in additional data beyond the first page.

[image: with sticky footer - cannot see more than 1 page of data]

The structure of my container page is the same as the create-react-app template:

```
<div className="App">
    <div className="App-header" />
    <div className="App-intro" />
    <div className="App-footer" />
</div>
```

and here is the CSS I use to freeze the header and footer:

```
html, body, #root {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.App {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.App-header, .App-footer {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.App-intro {
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

FWIW, [the official WindowScroller example](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/WindowScroller) accomplishes a frozen header using flex, but try as I might, I am not able to replicate it on my end.

I am at my wit's end after spending a whole entire day on this. I would really really appreciate any pointers to get this flex layout going with a functional window-scroller.

Comment: Link to a repro? You've only shared CSS so it's hard to trouble shoot. Throw something up on CodeSandbox.

Comment: @brianvaughn, thanks so much for your reply. Please find the repro at https://codesandbox.io/s/52j0vv936p  Line 4 in App.js - import './flex.css', brings in the flex styling. Commenting it out will show proper functionality.

Comment: > FWIW, the official WindowScroller example accomplishes a frozen header using flex, but try as I might, I am not able to replicate it on my end.

When I visit the example, I don't see a frozen header. I'm trying to achieve what you are describing here and would like to find an example that actually uses WindowScroller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the CodeSandbox you linked to (codesandbox.io/s/52j0vv936p)- window "scroll" events aren't reaching `WindowScroller`. That's because the `window` isn't actually what's scrollable, rather it's the middle "body" part. If that's what you want, you don't need to use `WindowScroller` at all and should remove it.

The only thing left that's broken is that your `AutoSizer` isn't getting a valid height because one of its parent `<div>`s doesn't have a correct height. For Stack Overflow convenience, here's the relevant bit:

> **Why is my AutoSizer setting a height of 0?**
>
> `AutoSizer` expands to fill its parent but it will not stretch the parent. This is done to prevent problems with flexbox layouts. If `AutoSizer` is reporting a height (or width) of 0- then it's likely that the parent element (or one of its parents) has a height of 0. One easy way to test this is to add a style property (eg `background-color: red;`) to the parent to ensure that it is the correct size. (eg You may need to add `height: 100%` or `flex: 1` to the parent.)

[Here is a diff](https://pastebin.com/R1dhg9W0) to your sandbox that shows what I'm talking about and [here is a fixed Code Sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/qlqkx2mrz4).

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, Brian! That worked like a charm. Exactly what I needed. You ROCK!!

Comment: @bvaughn very sad that fixed code sanbox doesn't work any more